# a simple "Hello" prints like "hellohellohellohello" in python socket

Tags: python, sockets

I just made a simple program using sockets in python but when i receive and print the message this happens.

`client.py` code

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("192.168.0.108",1234))

while True:
    s.send(bytes("Hello","utf-8"))
```

`server.py` code

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("0.0.0.0",1234))
s.listen(100)

while True:
    clientsocket, addr= s.accept()

    msg = clientsocket.recv(1024)
    msg = msg.decode("utf-8")
    print(msg)
```

`output:`

````
HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello```
````

I dont know why this is happening.
I hope you guys can help!

Comment: `while True:` makes your code repeat. Each time through the loop prints one `Hello`, but your loops run forever. (The top one sends as many `Hello`s as is can through a single socket; the bottom one receives as many sockets as it can and prints up to 1024 bytes from each; so the net result is that the bottom one runs only once, but the top one fills all 1024 bytes that the bottom one receives with `Hello`s).

Comment: for i in range(10):
    s.send(bytes("Hello","utf-8"))
 
idk about socket so

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i understand, but why do people use while loop for this then. i have seen a lot of youtubers using while loop.

Comment: @Shashankh_, the point of `while True` in the _server_ is to accept new connections after the first connection is done. The `while True` in the _client_ is just wrong, if you don't want the client to send `Hello` more than once.

Comment: (and in a real-world server that had longer-lived connections, you would probably fork off a thread for each one so new connections could come in while an existing one was still ongoing)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I see.. thank you for your help.